# Reduced color or paint

Tags: terminology

When I apply less amount of paint, how is the resulting color (or paint) called?

Reduced color? Mitigated color? Diluted color? Modified color? Limited color? Decreased color?

In other words, when I literally put less paint on the paper (for example, by applying it in thiner layer or by making lots of tiny dots), how to describe it in one word?

Comment: You need a thousand.

Comment: The color is *lighter*.

Comment: Or _paler_ (assuming the background colour doesn't show through – _less intense_ or _more translucent_ might work in this case, but need two words apiece).

Comment: A thin layer of pain, usually diluted with its solvent (water, turpentine) is called a *wash*.

Comment: My grandma did not use much paint when she had to redo doors and shutters. I used to call the resulting color _mean_.

Comment: Less than what? Thinner than what? These are comparative terms incorrectly used to describe what? Rephrase the question for a precise answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A liquid such as paint is reduced by way of thinning, so it is said to be thinned or thinned out.
"The watercolours of the painting were thinned out to a subdued degree."

A reduction in quantity of paint (a thinner layer) is not necessarily the same thing as a reduction in the color saturation. If you're referring to amount of paint, the thickness or thinness is more relevant and the color of the paint is irrelevant.

However, if you wish to refer to a reduction in the "color" attribute of the paint, then terms like pale, washed-out, diminished, dull, and faded are all common adjectives for colors.

Comment: As a side note, one exception comes to mind, in which the thicker the paint, the whiter the color: the _gouache_ technique, the variant with white paint for the binding agent.

Answer (score 1):

#### *washed-out, adj.*

> - Use colored pencils with a large amount of pigment. These will be more expensive, but brighter and will blend better than the cheaper brands. Less expensive colored pencils contain fillers to cut down on pigment costs and result in washed out colors and layering.
> - It is shot in washed out colors and is set mostly indoors, in cramped homes and apartments, creating a dreary looking movie.
> - I asked the moms to dress their kids in washed out colors of cream, brown, light pink, pale blue, and everyone looked beyond adorable.
> - During the day, outside of these hours, the light is usually too harsh and flat, resulting in washed out colors and boring photos.
> - When playing back video content, several issues might go wrong. The levels could be wrong, resulting in washed out colors (black is displayed as dark gray and white is displayed as light gray).

#### *drained, adj.*

> - The movie thrives in drained colors giving it a documentary type look.
> - The image (allthough not bad and your composition is good) is overexposed - look at the bright sky, colors look drained and the roof is so bright it almost hurts the eyes. As I said I like the image and you can give it a rework in Photoshop.
> - First, let's see what the original reflection pics look like. Okie dokie then, as you can see, it's upside down, and mirrored(of course ) but the colors look drained, or rather whiter

#### *faded, adj.*

> - Tried color page which printed in faded colors with brown where it should have been black.
> - Factors such as your contrast settings and simple age can cause your LED back light to lose power, resulting in faded colors.

#### *[pallid, adj.](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pallid)*

> 1) Having an abnormally pale or wan complexion: the pallid face of the invalid.
>   **2) Lacking intensity of color or luminousness.**
>   3) Lacking in radiance or vitality; dull: pallid prose.

#### *[pastel](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pastel)*

> adj.
>   A soft delicate hue; a pale color: a room done all in pastels.
>
> n.
>   Pale and soft in color.

---

An image consisting of "lots of tiny dots" can be said to be  **dithered**.

---

(the examples are googlable)

Comment: What's the source for first three items?

Comment: An image made of many tiny dots could be **pointillistic**.

Comment: @TheFrog Right. That one's the artier term of art, and its meaning focuses exclusively on points. _Dithered_ covers that meaning, but also means _faded_ by the technique OP described in the first part of the op. But for what OP's asking, they're synonymous. From GB: [This image shows a more limited, "impressionistic" palette with "pointillistic" (dithered) colour spots.](http://books.google.ba/books?id=99R1Tt2b704C&pg=PA366&lpg=PA366)

Comment: @jwpat7 My personal experience from an art course taken at Muskingum College one summer.

Answer (score 1):

***Unsaturated:***

> [Saturation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colchar.html), along with hue and brightness make up the three distinct attributes of color. Pink may be thought of as having the same hue as red but being less saturated. A fully saturated color is one with no mixture of white.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain that the art community has 'one word' for what you are describing.  I think you would say thinnly applied (thin not thick) or you would say lightly applied (light weight not heavy weight).